# WebGL: does using a single-channel texture format actually save (texture) memory?

Tags: webgl

From the [Khronos ref pages](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml):

> GL_LUMINANCE: Each element is a single luminance value. The GL
>   converts it to floating point, then assembles it into an RGBA element
>   by replicating the luminance value three times for red, green, and
>   blue and attaching 1 for alpha.

Does this apply to WebGL too? If so, does this imply that using textures formatted with less channels such as LUMINANCE does *not* save VRAM compared to using RGBA?

And how about RAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this apply to WebGL too?

Yes it does

> does this imply that using textures formatted with less channels such as LUMINANCE does not save VRAM compared to using RGBA

No, while this is implementation specific(and some implementations do actually choose to expand the data to RGBA before uploading) the expansion ought to happen on the fly, basically just providing one and the same value for every color component when sampling from such a texture within a shader.

> And how about RAM?

Once you call `texImage2D` the data is uploaded to VRAM and not kept in RAM as long as you don't do so(e.g. by holding on to a reference of the data).

Answer (score 1):

`GL_LUMINANCE` was deprecated and removed in OpenGL 3.2. Nowadays you specify the internal format explicitly with enums like `GL_R8`. Implementations allocate their internal storage with the specified format (even though this guarantee isn't there in the OpenGL spec, as per the as-if rule). I recommend not to use `GL_LUMINANCE` in WebGL either. Just use the explicit internal format and expand it in the shader as needed, or though texture swizzles.